# Can you trade a slow track for a fast track when multiclassing in Legend?

Tags: multi-classing, legend

In [Rule of Cool’s *Legend*](http://www.ruleofcool.com/), there are three “types” of track: “fast” (1st, 3rd, 6th, etc.), “normal” (1st, 4th, 7th, etc.), and “slow” (2nd, 5th, 8th, etc.), and each class has one of each so they cycle through the three tracks, gaining one circle per level (except 1st where they gain two).

*Legend* characters multi-class by trading one track for a track from another class. For instance, a Barbarian can trade away the Path of Rage track for the Ranger’s Professional Soldier track. Such a character gets Reap the Whirlwind instead of Rage at 1st level, for example.

However, there is no rule that I can find that prevents you from, e.g., trading your “slow” track for another class’s “fast” track. Can you do this? Does this mean you get two circles at each “fast” (and three at 1st!), and no circles at all on the “slow” levels?

**Note:** I am an avid fan of *Legend*, and have even had some of my contributions incorporated into Rule of Cool’s products. I have not been compensated for these contributions, and have no financial interest in the success of Rule of Cool or *Legend*. I merely like the system and want to share my knowledge of it. See [this meta question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1655/how-legit-is-it-to-askanswer-some-questions-about-my-favorite-rpg-system-that) for a discussion of this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes and no.

You can make this trade. You could trade the Barbarian’s Path of Destruction for the Ranger’s Professional Soldier, for example.

However, you gain the circles from the new track at the same levels you would have received them with the original track. As a result, you get Reap the Whirlwind at level 2, when you would have gotten Path of Destruction’s Cleave, even though a Ranger would ordinarily gain Reap the Whirlwind at 1st level. A Personal Touch then comes at level 5, not level 4 as it would for a Ranger.

The relevant rules come in the **Multiclassing** section in Chapter III:

> When you gain a new track via multiclassing, you pick one of your class’s tracks and give up that track. You instead gain the features of the new track, in order, at the levels that you would have gained features from the sacrificed track.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, but close enough.

Tracks are not 'fast' or 'slow', they're just Tracks. The thing is that you have three "*slots*" for tracks, one slot for each speed (and a second Normal slot in case of Full Buy-In), and each Class has its three Tracks placed in a certain position.

So, when you multiclass a Track, you're giving up one of your Tracks (therefore freeing its slot) and putting a different one in place. The slot is the same, so what slot it fills in the Class you took it from is irrelevant.

I hope this helps visualizing how it works.